# How to find Phrase, Simple Phrase, and Handle from grammar

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, handle, phrase

The following grammar:

```
S → AbB | bAc 
A → Ab | aBB 
B → Ac | cBb | c
```

The question ask me to find the Phrase, Simple Phrase and Handle for this string:

```
aAcccbbc
```

Without drawing parse tree, can anybody help me to get the Phrases, Simple Phrases and Handles please? If can, please show me step by step how to get for each type?